# Change URL according the loaded row from db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I`m trying to create simple site just to show images. URL for images are loaded **RANDOMLY** from the database and parsed into page by jQuery. So far it is working fine but I have troubles with URL. It is still the same no matter the loaded img.

**What I have:** *index.php*

**What Id like to have e.g.** *index.php?id=[value from db]*

Something like this [9gag](http://9gag.com/gag/a5Pg2Bg) if you press next it change the adress in the adress bar

Is there any change this could work somehow? Appreciate any idea. Thanks

This is my img-get.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from ".$table . " order by rand() limit 1" )) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    echo    "<h2>" . htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['title'])) . "</h2>" 
                   . htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['description'])) 
                   . "<br> <a href='" .$row['link'] ."'> Source </a>";

    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

This is my script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".next").click(function(){
            $(".x").load("img-get.php");
            });
        });
```

And in the index I`m calling it by

```
<button class='next'>
    <b>Load next</b>
</button>

<div class =" x">
    <?php include_once 'img-get.php' ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pushState here, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".next").click(function(){
        $(".x").load("img-get.php", function() {
          imageLink = $(".x").find("a").attr("href");
          window.history.pushState('', '', imageLink);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) thats what I have been looking for. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
               . "<br> <a href='" .$row['link'] ."?id=" . $row['id'] . "'> Source </a>";
```

Comment: Thanks, this will chage the link in the source but wont chage the actual adress in the adress bar for current page. It is not what I`ve actually looking for but I think I`m able to figure out how to do that now. So simple solution :) . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the header() command:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from ".$table . " order by rand() limit 1" )) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    echo    "<h2>" . htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['title'])) . "</h2>" 
                   . htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['description'])) 
                   . "<br> <a href='" .$row['link'] ."'> Source </a>";

    header("Location: http://www.example.com?id=".$row['id']);
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, same solution like above. It is parsing the ID but the adress in adress bar is still the same *index.php* instead of *index.php?id=foobar*